# Android delete a file in sdcard

Tags: java, android, file

I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` directory to save a file.  The initial directory I printed out is `/storage/emulated/0/myfilename.pdf` this path is stored to database, but then when I try to delete the file `new File("/storage/emulated/0/myfilename.pdf").delete` it could not find the file or could not delete.  I printed out the directory from `new File("/storage/emulated/0/myfilename.pdf")` and I saw the path is /file/[date] the date is in format 2019-12-2.

I set permission in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also set permission check and request permission at run time to read and write as follows:

```java
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, 
        new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                       Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

But I still could not delete the file.  Please help! thank you so much
The delete function is as below

```
  public void deleteAFile(File file){
//print debug
System.out.println("deleteAFile:>>>>>>>>>>>"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        if(file.delete())
        {
            System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to delete the file: "+file.getName());
        }
    }
```

Note that I used  targetSdkVersion and  compileSdkVersion = 28. minSDKVersion=19 in build gradle.

Comment: You need to explicitly request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime. You have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` twice in the `requestPermissions()` call. I'm not quite sure what you mean about the file path and date thing.

Comment: Thank Mike, I changed the WRITE thing, but it still not working.  About the path /file/2019-12-2 this is the path that I printed out inside the delete function.  The path before I grabbed from database is not /storage/emulated/0 any more, but /file/2019-12-2...

Comment: It's still not clear what's happening, exactly. Please [edit] your question to show us the file creation and deletion code, and the database save and retrieval.

Comment: I just edit the question with delete function. In the studio, I selected "View","Tool Windows", and "Device File Explorer" I saw the directory /storage/emulated is red word permission denied.  The sdcard directory has my file in it.  I have to manually delete the file then can save the new file

Comment: Hi Mike, I think I found the problem.  I manage the file path in several places.  When I reorganized them, It points to right location.  Thank you Mike